# Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary with Selenium in Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am running some Selenium-Tests. When I start them directly from Eclipse everything works fine. But when I Start them through Maven there the following Exception occurs:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException(Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\winapp\Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
null
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18040', time: '2012-11-02 09:44:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_35'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver)
```

I am using Firefox 10.0.10 ESR. I have also tried it with Selenium 2.25.0.

Here is my latest version of the pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.26.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.26.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I can support you with more information, please let me know.

edit: updated pom.xml

edit2: What wonders me most, is that i can run the tests from eclipse without ans problems. they just occure, if i call "mvn install" for example

Comment: The selenium-server artifact has a dependency to the servlet-api-2.5 artifact, which you should exclude, if your project will be run inside a web application container - From Selenium hq.org.

Comment: Also why you need the selenium-api dependency?

Comment: I just tried out some things. Now i have added the exclusion and deleted the selenium-api dependency, but the problem is still the same

Comment: You can try setting the `webdriver.firefox.logfile` system property to get the log from Firefox.

Comment: the problem is, that maven isn't able to start the firefox, so there are no logs ;)

Comment: check if there are any other process that occupy the port 7055?

Comment: there are no other processes occuping this port

Comment: downgrade your firefox to may be firefox 9 and try.

Comment: The latest version i could see in selenium download center is 2.25.0, try to use it instead of 26

Comment: how are you specifiying in your code to use the firefox binary...at C:\winapp\Firefox\firefox.exe.

Comment: I don't specify this in the code. this is where my installation of firefox is located, and selenium uses it automatically

Comment: Since you are using an ESR version of Firefox, can you try to replicate this on a different machine with a later version of FF? FF 15 seems to be the latest that Selenium supports and works well with.

Comment: Any chance this is related to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/webdriver/iljwYVtii3E

Comment: some kind of, but I tried the steps they explained there and it doesn't help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out where the problem was.

I loaded some extensions to add to the FirefoxProfile I use to instantiate the FireFoxDriver. These plugins where located under Java/main/resources. In Eclipse everything worked fine, but I couldn't access these plugins through Maven. After copying these files to a temporary folder, and load them from there it worked even from Maven.

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 30):

When I encounter this error it's usually one of two things.

**The Selenium version does not support the browser version**
Double check the Selenium/browser versions are the same when ran from Eclipse vs Maven.
Double check Eclipse and Maven are configured to use the same Selenium version.
This occurred for me when my browser auto updates so I turned that off in the browser.

**The Selenium tests are running in headless mode**
Unlikely if your manually executing mvn on the same machine as Eclipse.
This occurred for me when running Selenium through Maven on my Jenkins server.  The Jenkins server was running in headless mode.  Took me minute to figure out the headless stuff, think I set a DISPLAY env variable in Linux or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matthew, but I did the firs step plenty of times to be sure and the second one doesn't fit for me, because I run the tests on the same physical machine

Comment: After setting the DISPLAY env variable, was the problem fixed? I think I am running into the same issue.

Comment: DISPLAY fix it.  Also, if it works with a monitor connected or under HtmlUnit driver it's likely a headless issue.

Comment: FireFox can run updates as windows service on background, you must go to advanced settings - updates and uncheck it. Note your working version too, so you can install older when problems occur.

Comment: In my case, Mozilla got updated in between the run so half of ma tests got failed...

Answer (score 3):

Trying Adding this to your pom

**UPDATED:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.XX.X</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.XX.X</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: the latest version i have found was 0.9.7376. after adding this to my pom, there is still the same problem

Comment: The updated answer is working for me..If still problem exists then try passing FirefoxBinary Path through your test.

Comment: the problem is still the same. what do you mean by passing the path to the binary, because the path itself is right. when i open this path. firefox works fine

Comment: Please note that sometimes the dependency version mismatch can cause this issue. It is important that have the correct dep versions to match your browser version. I just upgraded to the latest dep version in maven and it worked.

Comment: this solved my problem as well - Selenium 43.0 + FF 45.0.2

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem that appeared after Linux updates.
We tested lots of combination of selenium versions (2.42.2 and 2.43.1) and firefox (27.0.1 to 32.0.2), but the problem was always present.

We are under OpenMandriva, and the project is under Eclipse and Maven.

We found a solution for us, that was to replace following maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

by all of following ones :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.1</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

I wonder if this solution is only hiding the real problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you've updated both Firefox and Selenium to the latest versions in trying to fix this issue, and you are still facing the problem, you may have updated Firefox using "Restart to update".

Shutdown Firefox and ensure that the Firefox executable is no longer running. Then try your test. It should work now.

I'm guessing this is related to when exactly the Firefox binary is updated when you use "Restart to Update"

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Firefox 36, also people were facing the same in 35 and 44.

For conclusion, upgrade your Firefox to 37 or downgrade it to anything less than 33.

Answer (score 0):

After battling this for a while and trying most (if not all) of the options listed here, I finally got rid of this error by removing an unused JAR - `ios-server-0.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar` in my build path, and using a combination of `FF34` and selenium jars `2.48.2`.

*Just wanted to post this as another option in case any one runs into this debilitating issue.*

Answer (score 0):

```
my recommendation is 

    ===> switch to firefox version 50.0 [latest One] , 

    ===> download the gecko driver from [.](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)  and 

    ===> Selenium version 3.0.1
     <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
     </dependency>

    ==> On your Code 
private WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "PATH to GECKO DRIVER");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    and yes you see the below output in your console :


    Dec 17, 2016 6:40:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
    14819XXXXXXX5   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\XXXXX\rust_XXXprofile.OXXXXXXXXXXX7S
    148XXXXXXXXX0   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
    148XXXXXXXXX1   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:XXXXXXX
    148198XXXX077   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53532
    Dec 17, 2016 6:40:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
    [Child 4104] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line XXXX
    Dec 17, 2016 6:41:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest selenium server version, You need to check the compatibility between browser and selenium server.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Cannot find the firefoxbinary path. 
Please set the firefox path in advance of using firefox driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
```

Answer (score -2):

The same problem also occures when there is no left space on disk where your Firefox cache folder located. Just free the space and launch your scripts!