# How to perform a Selenium test via Bamboo?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, maven-3, bamboo

We are trying to run some Selenium tests using Selenium CI . We are using maven to build the project and using Selenium web driver.

I followed an Blog post in this [link](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/how-to-use-selenium-in-continuous-integration-testing#comment-38432)
as a reference

When I run the maven project locally (without Bamboo) it worked fine. But when I tried to use it using a Bamboo agent in a windows server it gave an error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary
FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 
7055; process output follows:
Build info: version: '2.44.0', 
revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', 
time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40' System 
info: host: 'M',
ip:'myIP',
os.name: 'Windows 7', 
os.arch: 'amd64', 
os.version: '6.1', 
java.version: '1.8.0_11' 
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Then I searched the error assuming it was an error cause by a plug in.

Few of them are:

- [setUp method: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525636/setup-method-failed-to-connect-to-binary-firefoxbinary-usr-bin-firefox-on-por)
- [Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary with Selenium in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514338/failed-to-connect-to-binary-firefoxbinary-with-selenium-in-maven)

But nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an work around for the problem. I am posting that as an answer for anyone who will go through this situation. But I think there must be a better answer for this. Please post if you know a better way.

First (for us) this situation occurs only when we try to do the Selenium tests using Bamboo agent. Therefore if we look closely the agent is started by a service. So the process (Wrapper.exe) is running as it is run by the "SYSTEM". Therefore when the agent tries to run a program (in our case firefox.exe) that program will also started by the "SYSTEM".

**But the "SYSTEM" is not the user who s logged in to the PC. So it cannot interact with the Desktop. Therefore this error occurs.**

So what we have to do is run the agent process(Wrapper.exe) by my user, therefore when the agent starts another program such as firefox. It will be run as a process started by my user who can interact with the Desktop. 
When we do that, then the test runs like a charm!

As the work around what we did is this: Stop the service and run wrapper.exe using the "BambooAgent.bat" in "bamboo-agent-home\bin". You can do this by adding a shortcut of the bin file to the startup folder.

Comment: P.s Some times there could be a better way to do the tests in a Linux systems using XVFB