# Cannot use Webdriver in Mac OS X ?

Tags: macos, webdriver

Here is the StackTrace:
[image: I use it ok in Windows]

My OS version is 10.11.2 (15C50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because selenium is not able to detect the location of your firefox. You need to set `System.setProperty` to assist selenium about the location of firefox in your system

According to https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver there is a property you have to set to set the binary path:

```
webdriver.firefox.bin
```

For my system I have firefox in below location:-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","/Applications/Firefox20.0"); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Some system have location as below:-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin");
```

OR

There is a issue of some addions for that refer below link :-

[Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary with Selenium in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514338/failed-to-connect-to-binary-firefoxbinary-with-selenium-in-maven)

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Solved by replace it with the right version. Thanks~